# Changing UK visa from visitor to study

Tags: visas, uk, study, change-purpose-of-travel

Can I change my visa status from visitor to study while I'm still in UK?

Answer (score 3):

[Can you apply in the UK?](http://www.ukcisa.org.uk/Information--Advice/Visas-and-Immigration/Making-a-Tier-4-General-application-in-UK#layer-3000)

> the Immigration Rules only allow people who were last granted leave in certain immigration categories to make a Tier 4 application in the UK.

In short, no.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate, you cannot switch from a visitor visa into any other kind of UK visa category.